# How to track status of an users over static image in android?

Tags: android, gps, maps

[image]

As shown in the image, A static image is overlayed on map view and I want to track the users status using GPS whether he is in yellow or red, Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its easily possible, but you'll need to get down into the math a bit to do it.

Don't think of it as 'in which color is someone' but find your image center coordinates, and see how far away the user is from that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Projection`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/Projection) to convert between coordinates to/from pixels on the screen e.g. `mapView.getProjection().toPixels()`. If you draw these circle you should be able to know its location on the screen and determine in which circle is the user.

For example, you know the diameter for each circle and since they all have the same center as shown in your screenshot, you can easily know if the pixel in the green, yellow or red area by comparing the distance from the circles' center against the diameters of the three circles.